# Align divs in same line without using float and width

Tags: html, css

I tried to align 2 divs on the same line without using `float` and `width`. I am using below code.

```css
.first{
  color: #377fd9;
  font-size: 1.375rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 20px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecef;
}

.second{
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: end;
  padding: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">First</div>
<div class="second">Second</div>
```

Comment: Use flexbox to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the required layout, the borders and padding refer to the whole thing, not just the First div.

If you put both divs in a container and put that styling on the container, you could use flex to align the divs within container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 20px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecef;
}

.first {
  color: #377fd9;
  font-size: 1.375rem;
}

.second {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: end;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.first,
.second {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="second">Second</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Div is a block element by default and cannot be place side by side with other elements but you can change that by adding `display:inline-block` to your CSS like so

```css
.first{
  color: #377fd9;
  font-size: 1.375rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 20px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  display:inline-block;
}

.second{
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: end;
  padding: 8px 0;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">First</div>
<div class="second">Second</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it inside a parent element, and use `flexbox`.

You can use your other styles with this if you want. If you don't need the space between the div's, you can remove the `flex: 1` assigned to the div.

```css
.first{
  color: #377fd9;
}

.second{
  cursor: pointer;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="second">Second</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
    #main{display:grid;
        grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
        
      }
</style>


<div id="main">
    <div class="first">First</div>
    <div class="second">Second</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on flex box to perform that, For that you have to have a container which has `display` CSS property set to `flex` and all sub element will be align on the same line as the default Flex Direction is `ROW`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.first {
  background: #34D399;
}

.second {
 background: #1E3A8A;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="second">Second</div>
<div>
```

As you can see on the `.container div` selector I set all item to have equal width using `flex-grow: 1;`

Answer (score -1):

You can use flex in your layout. Working eg. i hope this will work for you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-banzai-dz5sm?file=/index.html